# Saving data to the database via JQuery .ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am attempting to save 2 pieces of information to the database via JQuery using the .ajax function. I want to save the postID and the userID in WordPress. I think I get the jist of most of the function but need to figure out how to send an array to the processing page so I can insert it. This is what i have written so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#saveme').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_data.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("This recipe has been saved in your profile area!");
            }

        });
    });
```

Can anyone shed some light one what goes into the data value to store the 2 pieces of information that I can send to the processing page?

I am using PHP and the code is in a .js file so I might need to also know to send the information over to the js file. Thanks!!

Comment: `data: "",` is empty `data` is key of `ajax` object in which you send the data to `save_data.php`.

Comment: data keyword stores the values which will be going to send on other page with ajax request you have to define your values in var id='2' and store it in data:"id="id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of Data to be sent to the server is JavaScript object containing zero or more key-value pairs or String. For your case

`data: {
            'postID' : $('#postID').val(),
                 'userID' : $(('#userID').val()
        },`

Comment: Thanks! Would I have to add hidden inputs for the postID and the userID on the page so I can get those?

Answer (score 1):

data should be a JSON object containing the data you want to save, i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#saveme').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_data.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {postID: "A123456", userId: "HGSADKJ"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("This recipe has been saved in your profile area!");
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: No such thing as a "JSON object". You have JSON that represents an object, but it's a string. What you're setting as the value of the `data` property in that code is a JavaScript object.

Comment: A JSON is not a String in any way. It's an object: `typeof {foo: 'bar'} == "object"`

Comment: No, that's incorrect. JSON is JavaScript Object Notation; it's the string representation of an object or array. What you've just described is a **JavaScript object**, not JSON.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.json.org/js.html First example uses a variable named myJSONObject. But I don't know, maybe Douglas Crockford doesn't know how to name his variables...

Comment: You're right, clearly he doesn't. The term "JSON object" is nonsense.

Comment: Then I guess they should rewrite the RFC for JSON (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) because he also used a variable named my_JSON_object there

Answer (score 0):

Just create a JSON object and send it:
(assuming say there is an element on the page by the id of postID and userID

```
var jsonData = { "postID" : $("#postID").val(),
                 "userID" : $(("#userID").va;() }


 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#saveme').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_data.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: jsonData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("This recipe has been saved in your profile area!");
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object". JavaScript has objects, JSON is a string that might represent one.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var postID='<?php the_id(); ?>';
   var userId='<?php author_id(); ?>';
        $('#saveme').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "save_data.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {postID: postID, userId: userId},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("This recipe has been saved in your profile area!");
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: They didn't forget to add it, the whole question is "what should it be?"